Convert object to model always returns null
I have a project that needs to convert an object from a method in unit test, but when I try to cast the object, it is always null.
var result = (IValueHttpResult)sut.Invoke("TEST");
var okResult = result.Value as LoanProgressResponse; 

okResult always null.
If I debug, I think there is no problem with the result I got from Invoke.
This is the value of result:

and this is the value of result.Value

and this is the LoanProgressResponse class:
public class LoanProgressResponse
{
    public string response_id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string status_code { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string status_description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string current_progress { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool is_approved { get; set; } = false;
}

I tried to explore but still failed like:
LoanProgressResponse okResult = result.Value as LoanProgressResponse;

Am I missing something?
I would be glad for any help.

What is result.Value.GetType()?

result.Value is not of type LoanProgressResponse so it is going to be null when you cast using as. There's nothing else we can help with since we have no idea what the other bits of your code are. What is sut, and what does Invoke do for example.

What that error is telling you is that result.Value is not a LoanProgressResponse

By default, without specifying the generic type for IValueHttpResult, the Value is an object type. You cannot directly cast the Value to LoanProgressResponse type unless you are working with (de)serialization.
using System.Text.Json;

var result = (IValueHttpResult)sut.Invoke("TEST");
var okResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LoanProgressResponse>(result.Value.ToString()); 

Otherwise, you have to use IValueHttpResult<Value>.
var result = (IValueHttpResult<LoanProgressResponse>)sut.Invoke("TEST");
var okResult = result.Value; 

Retrieve the value using Newtonsoft.Json.
var okResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoanProgressResponse>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Value!));


thank ,first solution work with some adjustment .. for second answer is not working
